# All Objects Passed Were None , Pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, group-by, dataframe, mean

I have this dataframe:

```
data = {'My_name':["abc","nc","there",""] , 'Val1':[44.20,22,None,44],'Val2':[50,20,40,72.2]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)  

  My_name     Val1  Val2
0   abc       44.2  50.0
1   nc        22.0  20.0
2   there     NaN   40.0
3             44.0  72.2  
4   there     28    60
```

And I used the following instruction to get the mean of the Values based on `My_name`:

```
 df2 = df1.where(pd.notnull(df1), None)  
 dcm = df2.groupby(['My_name']).agg([np.mean]) 

Exception: All objects passed were None
```

I've tried various tests and realized the error is because of the `None` whilst computing the mean.
I tried using the following instead to take care of `None` values:

```
df3 = df2.where(pd.notnull(df2['Val1']), None)
df4 = df3.where(pd.notnull(df3['Val2']), None) 
dcm2 = df4.groupby(['My_name']).agg([np.mean])
```

but I still get the same error. How do I ignore the NaN without having it spoil the mean?

Something like this will also do : 
Creating two dataframes . One without None values (in Val1 and Val2) and the other with None Values.
eg:

```
df_sub:



      My_name     Val1  Val2
    0   abc       44.2  50.0
    1   nc        22.0  20.0 
    3             44.0  72.2  
    4   there     28    60
```

and `df_sub2` :

```
   My_name    Val1  Val2
3  there      Nan   40.0
```

`df.dropna()` looks like a good function to do it, so I did :

```
df_sub = df2.dropna(subset=['Val1','Val2'])
```

How do i get the second dataframe?

Comment: Why do you try to replace the NaNs with None? NaN values will be ignored by the mean by default. So just do your grouping on the original dataframe `df1.groupby(['My_name']).agg([np.mean])`. Is that what you want? (and otherwise, show your expected result fo the grouby)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I don't think you need to replace the `NaN` values with `None`, as `NaN` is the default indicator for missing values and will be ignored by `mean` by default in pandas (`mean` has a `skipna` parameter that is True by default).
Furthermore, replacing it with `None` will make the columns of object dtype (not numeric anymore) and not all operations will work as expected.

So just try to do the grouping operation on the original dataframe:

```
dcm = df1.groupby(['My_name']).agg([np.mean])
```

Secondly, to split your dataframe, you can do:

```
In [26]: df1[pd.isnull(df1[['Val1', 'Val2']]).any(axis=1)]
Out[26]:
  My_name  Val1  Val2
2   there   NaN    40
```

and alternatively `df1[pd.notnull(df1[['Val1', 'Val2']]).all(axis=1)]` for the other subset, but this is indeed equivalent to the shorter `df1.dropna(subset=[['Val1','Val2']])`

Comment: that None with Nan was a good point , that helped me solve an error too. Thanks.. !!!